Using Selenium to filter CSS elements based on the content of the element
I'm trying to use Selenium to interact with a specific CSS class that contains the PMA string inside. I could use XPATH, but the location of the element occasionally changes. I currently have code below to pull the contents of the title-header:
pma = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h6.title-header')))

A hacky way to do it may be to just iterate through every title-header element and only keep the coordinates of the element that contains PMA. But as you can see below, there's multiple places where the title-header is in the DOM (there's over 900+). Is there a way for Selenium to navigate to the specific title-header with the PMA string inside?


Use xpath, check this answer.

have a look at CSS Selectors axes, you can try to navigate to the specific element h6.title-header with the help of mentioned methods.
However, in some specific cases CSS cannot help so one must have to choose Xpath. One such example would be locator based on text.
//h6[@class='title-header' and text()='PMA']

You'll have to compromise on performance and obviously it wouldn't work if you are testing a multilingual applicaiton cause the text would change.
